# Only one radio button can be clicked for entire form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, radio-button

I have a form that iterates through every student and evaluates them based on goals using radio buttons.  Each goal should have a score of 1-5.  At the moment, everything works fine except the radio buttons - only one radio button can be selected at a time in the whole form - ie, if goal one is marked as a 3, and then goal two is marked as a 4, goal one becomes unmarked.

Code is below:

[image: evaluation]

`evaluations - new.html.erb`

```
...
<div class="holder2 round clear">
    <%= form_for([@student, @evaluation]) do |f|  %>
      <% @subjects.each do |group, subjects| %>
        <% subjects.each do |subject| %>
          <h3><%= subject.name %></h3>  
          <%= render "goal_eval", :subject => subject, :f => f %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Next student", :class => 'big_button round unselectable' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

`goal_eval partial`

```
<table class="fixed">
  <tbody>
      <% subject.goals.each do |goal| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "goals")%>">
        <td class="goal_row"><%= goal.goal %></td> 
        <td>
          <% [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each do |score| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :score, score, goal_id: goal.id, student_id: @student.id %>
            <%= score %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>  
    <% end %>
      <% reset_cycle("goals") %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `radio_button_tag` has the same name.

You could name each button score_xx where xx is the id of the goal.

```
<%= radio_button_tag "score_#{goal.id}", score, goal_id: goal.id, student_id: @student.id %>
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, cheers - i had to change it to `score_#{goal.id}`, because the subject_id was the same for all three goals:

`<%= radio_button_tag "score_#{goal.id}", score, goal_id: goal.id, student_id: @student.id %>`

Answer (score 0):

Because they all have the same name/id in the same for, you need to scope nested forms with `fields_for` helpers.

Guess adding a `f.fields_for subject do |ff|` arround your prtial call and a `ff.fields_for goal` arround your *tr* each loop should do the trick.